# Keycloak - How to get all users for a realm and save them to application database?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I am building a REST API with spring boot and for authentication and authorization I am using Keycloak. Since the users are managed by Keycloak, my application database does not have the data of the users. But I want to store some attributes of the User entity from Keycloak in my application database, as user data will be required for audit purposes.

So what would be the best way to synchronize the application database User table with keycloak User table?

Comment: Do you need the users all at once or could you do this as they log in?

Comment: I am not able to add user when they login as I am using Keycloak access token endpoint for logging in the user so I cant intercept the login event from my API.

Answer (score 5):

I would implement a Keycloak plugin based on the **EventListenerSpi**. In the **EventListenerProvider** implementation you can concentrate on the user administration events only.

```
public class SyncEventListener implements EventListenerProvider
{
  private static final List<OperationType> SYNC_OPERATIONS = Arrays.asList(OperationType.CREATE, OperationType.UPDATE, OperationType.DELETE);
  @Override
  public void close() {}

  @Override
  public void onEvent(Event event) {}

  @Override
  public void onEvent(AdminEvent event, boolean includeRepresentation)
  {
    if ((event.getResourceType() == ResourceType.USER) && SYNC_OPERATIONS.contains(event.getOperationType()) )
    {
      // Write user data to external message queue or database
      externalStore.write(event.getOperationType(), event.getRepresentation());
    }
  }
}
```

The *event.getRepresentation()* returns a JSON object with all user data.
Of course you have to turn on admin events via Keycloak admin console (Events/Config/Admin Events Settings) to make this work.
Put both "Save events" and "Include Representation" to ON.

Comment: Thanks for answering. When I implemented this I get an error for `getResourceType()` as there is no method by this name in the event object. How do I fix this? Also can I have this file class as a part of my REST API?

Comment: You have to define the dependencies to the keycloak libraries. For gradle that is:    

_compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-server-spi', version: '3.3.0.Final'_    
_compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-server-spi-private', version: '3.3.0.Final'_