# How to get recently changed or modified user from keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, active-directory, keycloak

We have a scenario where we are polling users from Active directory to keycloak and this works perfectly fine and any recently changed user automatically gets added in keycloak .But here I have to load same users from Keycloak to my SpringBoot application DB on certain interval say 1 hour . So the high level data flow is like below
Active Directory -> KeyCloak ->Spring Boot Service Poll->Application DB
Need to find a best way to process only users who have recently been modified in keycloak so that I shall have less number of records to update in Application DB.

Keycloak keycloakInstance=// pass Keycloak URL to KeycloakBuilder

Userresource userResource=// using keycloakInstance pass realmName and getUsers
List uersListFfromkeyCLoak// Here need only users who have changed in last one hour[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a Keycloak plugin based on the **EventListenerSpi**. In your custom **EventListenerProvider** you can react to any change of user objects. You may write the change events to a message queue and read from that queue with your spring boot application.

For more information and a code snippet have look at my answer on that quite [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018791/keycloak-how-to-get-all-users-for-a-realm-and-save-them-to-application-databas/47022801#47022801).

Comment: I am using keycloak Server Version:4.8.1.Final. I got your point of implementing EventListenerProvider but not really sure if this class Implementation needs to be in my Spring Boot application (Which shall get a call back event on user modification ) or need to create a jar of the class implementation  ? It would be great if you can point any link where step by step configurations are mentioned.Added screenshot above where things you mentioned need to be configured but not sure how ?

Comment: Explored a lot but cant see any precise example of exactly where to have the implementation of EventListenerProvider i.e. either in SpringBoot application or need to place somewhere in keycloak ? I just tried to have the listener class in my springboot application and made all "Login Events Settings" to On in keycloak Events>Config and tried to delete and run sync activity but no luck

Comment: It is a Keycloak server plugin. See https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_events and https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/event-listener-sysout